# Redirect subfolder using HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have my site asp net pages at www.mydomain.com, and the blog was inside www.mydomain.com/blog. I had to move the blog to a subdomain, so I need to write a module to redirect any calls for any page within the blog to the new subdomain.

It works in my machine but not when I upload to the shared hosting. Any ideas what is wrong?

I wrote the following code

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string sourceUrl =  @"www.mydomain.com/blog";// @"localhost:51393/blog"
    string destinationUrl = @"blog.mydomain.com/blog"; 
    string currentLocation = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
   if(currentLocation.ToLower().Contains(sourceUrl))
   {
       System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
       System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 301;
       System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", currentLocation.Replace(sourceUrl, destinationUrl));
       System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();           
   }
}
```

And added these handlers

```
 <httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
  <add verb="*" path="*" type="MyHandler,App_Code.dll"/>
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

I know it is pretty similar to this one [httpHandler - subfolder issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715352/httphandler-subfolder-issue) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use IIS Rewrite

Here's a similar code that redirects 1 URL to another.  Little tweak will do it.  I got this working with my smarterasp.net hosting account.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}"
               redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This one looks promising. Let me give it a shot.

Comment: Sort of worked, but had to install the URLRewriter module. It works for aspx pages but I need it to work for all pages. Any ideas?

Comment: I marked this one as the answer as it guided me in the correct path. However I now have another issue with non existent pages that I am working out on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505834/intelligencia-urlrewriter-for-non-existent-or-non-aspx-pages