# Intelligencia URLRewriter for non existent or non aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to redirect all non existent pages to a different domain, as my blog was moved to a different domain.

So **www.mydomain.com/blog/asdf** should redirect to **blog.mydomain.com/blog/asdf**

Using Intelligencia URLRewriter module I can redirect blog/ but if I do blog/something I get a 404.

Even with a simple rule without regex like this one, it doesn't work for anything under the blog folder

```
<rewrite url="~/blog/^" to="http://blog.softwaresynergy.com/blog/" />
```

I also tried this to force all requests to go to the handler

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Any ideas on how to pick up everything under blog/ and redirect to the other domain?

Comment: Yes, but it is a shared hosting service, so I cannot modify anything directly in IIS. Needs to be all through web config.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following redirect rule:

```
<redirect url="^/blog/(.+)$" to="http://blog.softwaresynergy.com/blog/$1" />
```

put it at the top of your other rewrite rules, so it gets executed first, I think it should work.

Comment: Same problem, works locally but not in the host. Is there a security restriction.

Comment: You may be hitting this http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/installation/limitations

Comment: Probably, but I am using a shared hosting. Can I do this via config?

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewriting does not allow to rewrite path on other domain or subdomain. You can redirect the url by using this code in global.asax:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Request.Path;
    if (path.Contains("blog/"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://blog.softwaresynergy.com/blog/");
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this same technique for canonical redirects, that is add the www. but it doesn't work for php pages nor folders.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom 404 page.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Custom404.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"  />

<customErrors mode="On">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="/custom404.aspx" />
```

Inside the custom404 page I'd put code to do my redirect. Getting the path that caused the error would probably be a combination of...

```
Request.QueryString("aspxerrorpath");
Request.UrlReferrer;
```

Once I have the path they were trying to access just do a redirect.

```
Response.Redirect(NEW_SITE + PATH, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the change in a different way. Left the original site as php and did the redirect using php rewrite which works fine.

In the domain new.mydomain I did the aspx site

Not ideal, but worked for now.